# Point Domain to directory of a Bitnami Wordpress Multi-Site Instance

Tags: wordpress, apache, amazon-web-services, dns, bitnami

I am using a Wordpress Multi-site instance on AWS Lightsail and have a couple different Wordpress sites hosted with no issues (in the same instance).

I would like to host another website to the same Bitnami instance, but this domain does NOT have a Wordpress site. It is just a standard PHP website.

I assume that I need to point the nameservers to the AWS servers, but I am not sure how to specify what directory to point the non-Wordpress domain to.

For my Wordpress domains, I was able to use the "Sites" feature in Wordpress to configure multiple Wordpress domains.

Since this new domain isn't going to be a Wordpress site, do I need to modify the httpd-vhosts.conf file or something else? What specifically do I need to add?

Answer (score 2):

Bitnami Engineer here. You can copy the WordPress configuration files to a new folder

```
sudo mkdir -p /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/{conf,htdocs}
sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/htdocs
sudo cp -r /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/*.conf /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/
```

and then perform the following changes

- Edit the configuration files inside the /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/ directory. The httpd-prefix.conf should configure the Alias directive and you need to remove the DocumentRoot (remember to change the paths to the new ones). The httpd-app.conf should configure the Directory where your application is (remember to change the paths to the new ones)
- Include the new httpd-prefix.conf file in the /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf file
- Restart Apache

  ```
  sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
  ```

You can obtain more information in our documentation guide

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/administration/create-custom-application-php/

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for the late reply. I am still a bit uncertain. When doing above, should I also be changing my vhosts to add my additional domain name and point it to the right directory?  Right now I have 2 domains being hosted through Wordpress Multi-site. I want to maintain that, but add a new domain that points my custom application. Will doing the above hurt my WP Multi-site domains?